# How to get order to reflect historical price rather than the price where the entry signal triggers?

Tags: pine-script

Clarification: I have a strategy where i want to enter on market open, but the signal for the strategy of course can not trigger until the first bar has closed. The issue with this is that my entry is delayed and alters the result of backtests.

So i am wondering if there is a work around where the signal triggers as usual after the bar has closed, but the entry price is that of the open of the bar rather than the close(signal trigger)? So a historical price, im not sure pine script allows for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the signal received inside the bar to be executed at the open of this bar?

It is not possible for the broker to execute orders that way, so it is impossible to write an algorithm that will do this through a Pine. Because it can't make any practical sense.

For example, we look at the one hour timeframe (for simplicity, let's say that symbol ticks only once per second), the bar opened at 14:00:00 and should close at 14:59:59, at 14:10:00 on one of the real-time ticks your condition for generating an order was fulfilled, this happens inside this bar, therefore it is impossible to open an order by the price that was at 14:00:00 since it was in the past. You can open an order at the next tick, for example, at 14:10:01, 14:10:02, and so on.

If you want to open a market order at the next tick after the condition appears, then the strategy must be calculated not only at the last tick of the bar (default), but also at each real-time tick. This can be done using parameter `strategy(calc_on_every_tick = true)`.